# How to get the Client ip address in an EJB3 Interceptor?

Tags: java, jndi, ejb-2.x

Often it's useful for Auditing or security purposes to get the IP Address of the client making a remote EJB3 Call. This information is not readily available in the Context of an EJB3 Bean.  Here's a hack to be able to achieve this in JBoss 4.x.

Comment: What hack are you talking about?

Comment: An talking about EJB remote get client IP Address in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer on this page 
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToGetTheClientIpAddressInAnEJB3Interceptor?_sscc=t

Basically it uses the thread name to obtain the ip address as each call is launched in its own thread...