# send client info to ejbs

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-2.x

I need to add certain functionality to an existing ejb projects.
Specifically - the client info, such as IP addres, login credentials (who is connected) and client application name
My bean is a stateless, so I worry there is an issue with such an approach..
My client code currently has the following:

```
private static MySession getmySession() throws RemoteException {
  if(mySession != null) return mySession; //mySession is a private variable
  try {
      Properties h = new Properties();
      h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
      h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, serverUrl ); //t3://localhost
      InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(h);
      mySessionHome home = (mySessionHome) ctx.lookup( "mySessionEJB" );
      mySession = home.create();
      return mySession;
  } catch(NamingException ne) {
      throw new RemoteException(ne.getMessage());
  } catch(CreateException ce) {
      throw new RemoteException(ce.getMessage());
  }
 }
```

Ideally, I would like my 'mySession' know about the client at the point it is returned.
If that may not be possible,
I would like to send a client info at the time a particular method of MySession is called.
Somewhere in this code

```
public static List getAllMembers() throws RemoteException, CatalogException    
{
 getMySession();
 List list = mySession.getAllMembers() );
 return list;
}
```

There are quite many such methods, so this is less desirable.  but I will take it if it solves the task.
At the end of the day, when "getAllMembers()" executes on the server, I want to know particular info of which client has called it. (there can be many different, including webservices)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing - what are you doing with the client information?  If you're planning to use it for auditing, this sounds like a perfect use for [Interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/EJB3_Interceptors.html)!

The EJB way to access user information is via the user's [Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bncaa/index.html), and there's no problem using this in a stateless bean.  You may find that this doesn't get all the information you would like - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748442/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-an-ejb3-interceptor) suggests getting the user IP isn't entirely supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am dealing with an older system, written usign EJB-2.1.  And a "quick" translate into EJB3 is not very welcome at the moment

Comment: Ok, one other approach to consider might be catching this at the web server level.  Of course this wouldn't allow you to correlate calls with EJB activity, but it sounds like a server access log would have a lot of what you want out of the box.

Comment: 1)  I tried to do this using current Thread name - and parsing out Ip address out of it.  However, on weblogic - instead of IP address, it has the name "[ACTIVE]", and no real IP address.
2) I tried using rmi's class RemoteServer, getting the clientHost() - it gives the same output as above, "[ACTIVE]",

Comment: Yes, an HTTM log - Access.log file on weblogic has the IP address info.  So, as a developer I can go in and figure it out using few other logs, and associating items when I am investigating.  The issue is, that I want to have that info inside the regular log4j output for other users to be able to do that.  In addition, we have many applications using a particular bean, so I also need to send which application it is. (somehow)